# Scope of a variable INSIDE (null) and OUTSIDE (!null) a LISTENER in Java

Tags: java, android, realsense

i have a problem with my android application for making object detection using Google MLKit and a Depth camera by intel the RealSense D435i.

After obtain the data from the camera and turn into a bitmap i pass the image to the object detector and if any object is recognized the app draw an overlay over the image with bounding box, label and the distance. here comes the problem: the function getDistance(x,y) doesn't work properly and get an error: the coordinates are out of range but in reality are not if I print them.

So the problem is that the variable "depth" outside the listener is okay, inside the listener is empty.

I'm not sure if the workflow of getting the frames are correct so please take a look.

here is the problematic code

````
        int count = 0;
        final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                try (FrameSet frames = mPipeline.waitForFrames()) {
                    try (FrameSet processed = frames.applyFilter(mAlign)) { // align qua
                        try (Frame depthFrame = processed.first(StreamType.DEPTH)) {
                            try (Frame colorFrame = processed.first(StreamType.COLOR)) {

                                VideoFrame videoFrame = colorFrame.as(Extension.VIDEO_FRAME);
                                DepthFrame depth = depthFrame.as(Extension.DEPTH_FRAME);
                                DepthFrame depthColorized = depthFrame.applyFilter(mColorizer).as(Extension.DEPTH_FRAME); // colorizer qua

                                int c_size = videoFrame.getDataSize();
                                int c_height = videoFrame.getHeight();
                                int c_width = videoFrame.getWidth();
                                byte[] c_data = new byte[c_size];
                                videoFrame.getData(c_data);

                                int d_size = depthColorized.getDataSize();
                                int d_height = depthColorized.getHeight();
                                int d_width = depthColorized.getWidth();
                                byte[] d_data = new byte[d_size];
                                depthColorized.getData(d_data);

                                ImageView img1 = findViewById(R.id.screen_view);
                                ImageView img2 = findViewById(R.id.screenD_view);

                                if (c_data.length != 0 && d_data.length != 0 ) {
                                    realsenseBMD = rgb2Bitmap(d_data, d_width, d_height);
                                    //Bitmap realsenseBMD = loadBitmapFromAssets();
                                    realsenseBM = rgb2Bitmap(c_data, c_width, c_height);
                                    InputImage image = InputImage.fromBitmap(realsenseBM, 0);
                                    CustomObjectDetectorOptions customObjectDetectorOptions =
                                            new CustomObjectDetectorOptions.Builder(localModel)
                                                    .setDetectorMode(CustomObjectDetectorOptions.SINGLE_IMAGE_MODE)
                                                    .enableMultipleObjects()
                                                    .enableClassification()
                                                    .setClassificationConfidenceThreshold(0.5f)
                                                    .setMaxPerObjectLabelCount(1)
                                                    .build();
                                    if (count % 3 == 0) {
                                        ObjectDetector objectDetector = ObjectDetection.getClient(customObjectDetectorOptions);
                                        objectDetector
                                                .process(image)
                                                .addOnSuccessListener(
                                                        new OnSuccessListener<List<DetectedObject>>() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onSuccess(List<DetectedObject> detectedObjects) {
                                                                graphicOverlay.clear();
                                                                if (detectedObjects.size() > 0) {
                                                                    for (DetectedObject detectedObject : detectedObjects) {
                                                                        float depthValue = 0;
                                                                        try{
                                                                            **depthValue = depth.getDistance(detectedObject.getBoundingBox().centerX(), detectedObject.getBoundingBox().centerY());**

                                                                        }catch (Exception e) {
                                                                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Inside listener: " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                        }
                                                                        ObjectGraphics drawBoundingBoxLabel = new ObjectGraphics(detectedObject, graphicOverlay, image.getWidth(), depthValue);
                                                                        drawBoundingBoxLabel.drawBoundingBoxAndLabel();
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        })
                                                .addOnFailureListener(
                                                        new OnFailureListener() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                                                TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.labelTextView);
                                                                textView.setText(e.getMessage());
                                                            }
                                                        });

                                        try {
                                            float depthValue2 = depth.getDistance(depth.getWidth() / 2, depth.getHeight() / 2);
                                            distanceView.setText("distance: " + String.valueOf(depthValue2));
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }

                                    //mySurfaceView.setBitmap(realsenseBM);
                                    //mySurfaceViewDepth.setBitmap(realsenseBMD);

                                    img1.setImageBitmap(realsenseBM);
                                    img2.setImageBitmap(realsenseBMD);
                                    count++;
                                }
                            }catch (Exception e){
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ColorFrame try: " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "DepthFrame try: " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ProcessedFrame try: " + e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                mHandler.post(mStreaming);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "streaming, error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };```
````